# Не удается десериализовать класс контейнер

Tags: c#, десериализация

Имеется небольшая библиотека классов. Сериализовать в json удается без проблем. А вот при десериализации возникает исключение Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot create and populate list type BooksLib.Bookstore`1[BooksLib.Product]. Path '', line 1, position 1.".

```
  public class Product : IComparable<Product>
{
    
   
    public double Price
    {
        
        ...
    }
    private string title;
    /// <summary>
    /// Название
    /// </summary>
    public string Title
    {
       ...
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Price = {Price:f2}";
    }
    
    public static explicit operator double(Product product)
    {
        return product.Price;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Product other) => Price.CompareTo(other.Price);

    public Product(double price, string title)
    {
        Price = price;
        Title = title;
    }
   
}
```

}

```
 public class Book : Product
{
    private short numberOfPages;
    private short year;
   
    private double rating;

    public Book(double price, string title, short numberOfPages, short year, double rating):base(price,title)
    {
        NumberOfPages = numberOfPages;
        Year = year;
        Rating = rating;
    }

   
    public short NumberOfPages
    {
        get => numberOfPages;
        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }
   
    public short Year
    {
        get => year;
        set
        {
            ...
            year = value;
        }

    }
   
    public double Rating
    {
       ...
        }
    }
   
    public string stringGetShortInfo() => $"{NumberOfPages}.{Year}.{unique(Title)}.{Math.Round(Rating,2) * 100}";
    
    private int unique(string str)
    {
       ...
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

}

```
 public class Bookstore<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : Product
{
    private List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        items.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < items.Count; index++)
        {
            yield return items[index];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }


}
```

}

```
 class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<Product> books = new Bookstore<Product>();
    static string path = "../../../Подготовка к экр 1 Вариант/books.json";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            Deserialize();
            foreach(var i in books)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
    static void Deserialize()
    {
       
            if(File.Exists(path))
            {
               
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
                {

                JsonSerializer deserializer = new JsonSerializer();
                books = (Bookstore<Product>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Bookstore<Product>));
                
                
                }
              
            }
  
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Добавьте json тоже

Comment: Для начала, почему такой ужасный метод десериализации? Зачем инициализировать deserializer? Stream зачем? Зачем присвоение типа? Ведь можно просто `books = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Bookstore<Product>>(File.ReadAllText(path));`, ну или если так нужен `Stream`, то `ReadAllText` меняете на объект потока. Далее, для чего вам кастомная коллекция? В чем ее смысл? Мне почему то кажется, что вы изобретаете велосипед. Ну а по поводу ошибки - [первая ссылка гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36927170).